# ASP.NET MVC razor form with knockout won't validate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js, validation

I have model like this (simplified)

```
public class User
{
  [Required]
  public string UserName { get; set; }

  // Other fields
}
```

An MVC razor view with knockout `viewModel` that looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "profileEditorForm" }))
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

  @Html.LabelFor(n => n.UserName)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(n => n.UserName, new { data_bind = "value: UserName" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(n => n.UserName)

  @* Other fields *@    

  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" alt="" title="" />
    <a href="/">Cancel</a>
  </p>
}


<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    var vm = new viewModel(@(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model))));
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    $("#profileEditorForm").validate({
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert('Validating ' + ko.toJSON(vm));
        if (vm.save)
          window.location.href = "/";
        return false;
      }
    });
  });

  var viewModel = function(model) {
    var self = this;
    self.UserName = ko.observable(model.UserName);
    // Other fields

    self.save = function() {
      alert('Saving ' + ko.toJSON(self));
    }
  };
};
</script>
```

I cannot get it to give me client side validation even though it goes through validate function (the alert insertion indicates that) and then straight into save and to posts back to MVC action something that is not valid.

Can you please help me how to enable client side validation (it is enabled in web.confir) on this form. Is it Knockout that ruins the day (although all the bindings are working perfectly fine? Or is it something I am looking at and don't see?

Help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation doesn't work with knockout bindings....

You have to duplicate the validation in client side. The faster way is using knockout validation plugin, but it is slow when you have a lot of data..

https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation

Or you can just use jquery validation.

Answer (score 0):

Model Validation Will not work in knockout binding you have to download [knockoutValidation.js](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation) file and use knockout validations

Example :

Validating UserName in KnockoutJS

```
var self = this;

self.UserName = ko.observable(UserName).extend({
    required: {
        message:"Please enter User Name"
    }
});
```